# How to update test box in Serial_data_received event?

Tags: c#

I found tons of answers to this question, but none worked for me so far and I am desperate to fix my issue.
This is using C#.

I am using delegate method to invoke my function which updates the test box and some other controls.

I open the Form with Frm.ShowDialog() and close with this.Close();

My delegate declarations are in Class header :

```
    public delegate void AddDataDelegate(String myString);
    public AddDataDelegate myDelegate;
```

I call the following in Form_Load with event attachment to serial port data received event.

```
    private void frmNewRecipe_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    //    if (Singleton.wickController.tinyGConnected) { panel1.Enabled = true; }
        populateRecipeNames();
        populatePalletNames();

        this.myDelegate = new AddDataDelegate(AddDataMethod);

        globalSingleTon.Singleton.Instance.tinyGSerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(tinyGSerialPort_DataReceived);                  
    }
```

---

```
public void AddDataMethod(String s)
    {

        int i = 0;
        txtSerial.AppendText(s + "\n");

        if (s.Contains("stat:3") || s.Contains("Stop"))
        {
            globalSingleTon.Singleton.wickController.stageReady = true;
        }

        if (s.Contains("pos"))
            {................
```

Data received event:

```
    private void tinyGSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        string s = "";
        //            try
        {
            while (globalSingleTon.Singleton.Instance.tinyGSerialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                s = globalSingleTon.Singleton.Instance.tinyGSerialPort.ReadLine();

                {
                    if (InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        txtSerial.BeginInvoke(this.myDelegate, new Object[] { s });
                    }
                    else AddDataMethod(s);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

---

Here is the issue now. This whole thing works fine when I open the form for the first time after running the application. I found that during debugging that 
"InvokeRequired" is true for the first time when I run but fail when I open the form second time (without closing the application). It is likely that my txtSerial control is in a different thread than the delegate.

When InvokeRequired is False, I see that the txtSerial.appendText triggers but nothing gets into the control.

**If I close the form and reopen, nothing works.** No change with using dispose() either. Could some one help fixing this issue ? I am really frustrated with this now. I am sure this is related to threading but could not get it fixed with many solutions I found here so far.

I have more updates. I was able to narrow it little further down. Problem happens when InvokeRequired is false. When I call text update method when "InvokeRequired" is false (IsHandleCreated is true), Text boxes aren't getting anything. (No errors either.) However interestingly, Message Box shows all incoming data in "s" string.

Why is not the controls getting values ?

```
private void tinyGSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        string s = "";
        //            try
        {
    //        if (!txtSerial.IsHandleCreated) { txtSerial.CreateControl(); }
            while (globalSingleTon.Singleton.Instance.tinyGSerialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                s = globalSingleTon.Singleton.Instance.tinyGSerialPort.ReadLine();

                {
                    if (InvokeRequired)
                        {
                        IAsyncResult result = this.BeginInvoke(this.myDelegate, new Object[] { s });
                        this.EndInvoke(result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (IsHandleCreated)
                        {
                            txtSerial.Text = s + "\n";
                            txtSerial.Text = "This is the test";
                            txtReceipeName.Text = s;
                            MessageBox.Show(s);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks,
Pubudu

Comment: If you are opening that form more than once, then it looks like you keep adding this event `globalSingleTon.Singleton.Instance.tinyGSerialPort.DataReceived` more than once, which makes it run more than once.  Only add events once.

Comment: Data received event works fine. If I pus a message box, it keeps popping up with data coming of read event. So I don't think I am messing anything there. I have not now narrow it down further. Issue is Handler is not created when I invoke. I don't understand why my handler is not created when the form is already loaded.

Comment: Put a line break on `globalSingleTon.Singleton.Instance.tinyGSerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(tinyGSerialPort_DataReceived);` in your form load event.  If you hit it more than once when running the program and testing it, you are adding the event more than once.

Comment: Sorry my bad, that the IsHandlercreated is true. But controls aren't getting any information except message box. (I confirmed that Data received is triggered only once whenever I open form. Actually I remove the method when I close the form. InvokeRequired is false when this problem happens. It is true when I open for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below. Added `this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate` for the statement which requires UI controls property change e.g. `txtSerial.AppendText(s + "\n");`

```
public void AddDataMethod(String s)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        int i = 0;
        txtSerial.AppendText(s + "\n");

        if (s.Contains("stat:3") || s.Contains("Stop"))
        {
            globalSingleTon.Singleton.wickController.stageReady = true;
        }

        if (s.Contains("pos"))
            {................
        :
        :
    });
}
```

Comment: No, this is not helping. I get the following exception when I run second time after closing the form first time.